# Semicolon at an end of a command causes an error and any command I put in never returns anything

Tags: server, mamp

I'm trying to experiment on my MySQL server for the first time running from MAMP server. Here's a screenshot of what I put into the command line and how it responded: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZoAU.png

Each new "->" is what happens when I hit enter. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `->` prompt is for line continuation. It is meant to continue writing your query on multiple lines. Adding a `;` terminator would let mysql know that it should execute the query, which will fail because the multiline query in the screenshot is invalid and you will return to the `mysql>` prompt.